# Time complexity for a solution to the heater problem on Leetcode

Tags: python, while-loop, time-complexity, big-o

Considerng this python solution from a popular question on Leetcode :

```
 def findOptimalRadius(houses, heaters):
        houses.sort()
        heaters.sort()
        last = len(heaters) - 1
        x1,x2 = 0,0
        res = 0
        for house in houses:
            while x2 < last and house > heaters[x2]:
                x1, x2 = x2, x2+1
            dist1,dist2 = abs(heaters[x1] - house), abs(heaters[x2] - house)
            res = max(res, min(dist1,dist2))
        return res
```

(given N houses and M heaters)

Apparently the space complexity is considered to be O(N log N + M log M) if we sort both arrays at the beginingg, and O(N+M) if they are already sorted.

But I don't understand why the for loop and the nested while loop only accounts for O(N+M).

Shouldn't it be O(N*M) since they are nested, and in worst case the while loop would iterate through all the heaters?

Thank you for helping me understanding how to calculate the time complexity in this case

Comment: could you explain the problem this is a solution too?

Comment: im not sure if I can add a link here, but you can easily find the problem description on google typing "leetcode heaters problem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is O(N+M) because second loop is running only once for each element. If you notice, x2 is never decreasing, it always continues from the last state and increases for 1, so when it reaches value last loop is forever ended. So, instead of passing every element in array heaters every time, it passes trough it only once and when it reaches its end, even tho there are still elements in array houses, while loop won't be initiated.

As for your intuition. It would be correct in case that for every element in array houses you would traverse every heater but this is not the case.

Notice that having nested loops doesn't automatically mean that time complexity is O(N*M) (in this case) or O(N^x) (x is number of nested loops). You must analyze what is each individual loop doing.

Edit:
Illustration for comment bellow:

```
N=20
M=15

i= current for loop element 
j= current while loop element

i=1 -> j = 1 , 2 , 3 , 4
i=2 -> j = 4 , 5
i=3 -> j = 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 
i=4 -> j = 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 , 15
i=5 -> j = 15 (while loop is at its end so it won't be initiated)
i=6 -> j = 15 
 .
 .
 .
i=20 -> j = 15
```

You can notice that while loop will end and never be initiated again when it reaches the end of array heaters. So the while loop has complexity O(M), for loop has complexity O(N). Since the while loop is not restarted for every i and just continues from the last state total complexity is O(N+M) instead of O(N*M).

Just think about the fact that you are passing trough every element in heaters only once, same for houses (you will never revisit some element).

If you revisited whole array of heaters for every house then complexity would indeed be O(N*M).

Comment: As you mentioned, the x2 is always continuing increasing until it reaches the value last. But the value last represent the number of heaters. So in worst case scenario it is iterating through all the heaters, within the loop that iterate through all the houses right?

Comment: Yes, in the worst case it will iterate trough all of the heaters but since the while loop is not restarted when it does iterate trough all of them, every subsequent pass in the for loop will just ignore the while loop.  So, for example, if for loop is on the first element of the array of houses and while loop iterates trough all heaters and reaches last element, when for loop passes on to the next house while loop will be at its end so it would just be skipped since x2==last. Even tho the while loop is nested it isn't really dependent on the for loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great explanation now I got it!